# Replace special characters from clipboard before pasting

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I use a little js function which permits to paste the content of the clipboard in a textarea. see below.
the datas I paste are from excel, and are delimited with special characters `\r\n`
My need is to replace this special characters with a comma "," directly before the paste
Is there an easy way to do it ? thanks per advance

```js
 function Coller() {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then(clipText =>
  document.getElementById("textarea").innerText = clipText);
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="Coller()">Coller</button>

<textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Comment: You should clarify whether you want the edit to happen before the clipboard is pasted or at the beginning of the content after the paste event. It's quite confusing

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with the String.prototype.replace() functions. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

you can use it like this:

```
function Coller() {
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(clipText =>
    document.getElementById("textarea").innerText = clipText.replace(/["]/gm, '').replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, ','));
}
```

In this case `\r`(created on Mac), `\n`(created on Linux) and `\r\n` (created on Windows) will be replaced.

- `g` stands for global, so every special character in your string will be replaced
- `m` stand for multi line, so even though your text has several lines, all special characters will be replaced

Comment: It works perfectly ! thanks a lot !
I have juste to clean some " which are inserted (don't know why). Searching a way to clean them before the paste.

Comment: @mattheoh I have adjusted the code accordingly. If the main answer was helpful please mark it as this so other people with the same question can find it ;)

Comment: You're too fast ^^ 
That's perfect, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Hi again @Kris ! In fact it worls perfectly on Chrome Browser, but not on Firefox or Edge..
TypeError: navigator.clipboard.readText is not a function
I tried some tips I found, but nothing works...
Would you have a brilliant idea ?! ^^ 
Thanks again for your help

Comment: @mattheoh `navigator.clipboard.readText()` just doenst work on Edge or Firefox. But have you tried using the `execCommand()` function instead? Its explained [here] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the special characters with regex:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").innerText = clipText.replace(/\r\n/g, ',');
```

Sample example:

```js
let text = "Cherry\r\nOrange\r\nApple"

console.log(text.replace(/\r\n/g, ','))
```